# Combine two queries in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have 2 queries to retrieve `faultCount` and `responseCount` as follows and it works fine.

```
select count(*) as faultCount,
       COMP_IDENTIFIER 
from CORDYS_NCB_LOG 
where AUDIT_CONTEXT='FAULT' 
group by COMP_IDENTIFIER  
order by responseCount;

select count(*) as responseCount,
       COMP_IDENTIFIER 
from CORDYS_NCB_LOG 
where AUDIT_CONTEXT='RESPONSE' 
group by COMP_IDENTIFIER  
order by responseCount;
```

I need to join to get the columns like this: `COMP_IDENTIFIER,faultCount,responseCount`. The following query does the job. But it takes a long time to execute (> 16 sec).

```
select count(case AUDIT_CONTEXT when 'FAULT'    then 1 end) as faultCount,
       count(case AUDIT_CONTEXT when 'RESPONSE' then 1 end) as responseCount,
       COMP_IDENTIFIER 
from CORDYS_NCB_LOG 
group by COMP_IDENTIFIER  
order by responseCount;
```

I'm looking for a simple and faster query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually you should do order by on a column which has been indexed. Also depending on your database size, you are checking each row for 'RESPONSE', so try and do query on a column that you have indexed. Also if possible dont search for a string first. Rather try and shorten the database table by some other criteria and then search the string on a smaller subset.

Comment: I think you should remove `mysql` tag..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason this is taking longer is that you're reading all rows in `CORDYS_NCB_LOG` even where `AUDIT_CONTEXT` is not `FAULT` or `RESPONSE`, which are the only rows you're interested in.

You can add this to the `WHERE` clause of your existing query:

```
select count(case AUDIT_CONTEXT when 'FAULT'    then 1 end) as faultCount,
       count(case AUDIT_CONTEXT when 'RESPONSE' then 1 end) as responseCount,
       COMP_IDENTIFIER 
from CORDYS_NCB_LOG
where AUDIT_CONTEXT in ('FAULT', 'RESPONSE')
group by COMP_IDENTIFIER  
order by responseCount;
```